# relocating pictures on my htc wildfire

Tags: android, android-image

I want to use a picture that was sent in a text message as my wallpaper but having selected 'save image' I can't find it anywhere else on my phone! Can anyone tell me how to relocate pictures to my gallery please?

Answer (score 0):

When you save a picture from a text, it saves to the Downloads folder on your SD card.

Follow these instructions to make it your wallpaper (skip to the "Assigning Wallpaper" section): http://www.ehow.com/how_8220310_use-downloaded-pictures-wallpaper-droid.html

Comment: Many thanks...job done!! Clear,straightforward instructions got the job done in seconds...why can't life always be so??